# Android - create callback using Flow

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to understand Flow but few thing are not clear to me. I have a simple interface :

```
interface Operation<T> {
    fun performAsync(callback: (T? , Throwable?) -> Unit)
    fun cancel()
}
```

then I have a manager class with function :

```
fun<T : Any> Operation<T>.perform(): Flow<T> =
        callbackFlow {
            performAsync {
                value , exception ->
                when {
                    exception !=null -> close(exception)   //operation had failed
                    value == null -> close() //operation had succeeded
                    else -> offer(value as T)
                }
            }
            awaitClose { cancel() }
        }
```

let's say I have a very simple operation - trying do use gson to serialize object to JSON :

```
fun convert () {
try {
  val carJSON = gson.toJson(carObj)
  //send Car value
} catch (e : Exception) {
  //here I want to send exception and receive it in callback in activity/fragment.
}
}
```

Can you explain me, please, how to observe Exception (or T value) and send/receive it in Activity/Fragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you use a sealed class.

```
sealed class Operation<out V, out E> {

data class Result<out V> (val data: V) : Operation<V, Nothing>()

data class Error<out E> (val error: E) : Operation<Nothing, E>()

companion object {
    inline fun <V> build(operation : () -> V) : Response<V, Exception> {
        return try {
            Value(operation.invoke())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you need response from some callback function as flow do the following.

```
fun someFunction() : Operation<Flow<String>, Exception> {

val flow = callbackFlow<String> { 

val callback = object : someCallback {

       onResult(result: String) {
          offer(result)
       }
       onError(e: Exception) {
          throw e 
       }
}

awaitClose { callback.remove() } //Just an example of a callback

}

return Operation.build { flow }

}
```

Now in Activity,

Simply get the result within some method like,

```
when(someFunction) {

is Operation.Result -> collect(someFunction().data)
is Operation.Error  -> handleErrorAsHoweverYouWant(someFunction().error)

}
```